# KendoReact DataGrid Change Date format in GridColumnMenuFilter to dd-MM-yyyy

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

I'm using Kendo React DataGrid `GridColumnMenuFilter` to filter the dataset using `dd-MM-yyyy` format. But default format is `month/day/year`. How can I change the Date filter format in ColumnMenu? or Can anyone suggest me to handle this scenario please?

Note: I need to display data in`dd-MM-yyyy` format and filter with same format.
[Official Reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/filtering/#toc-column-menu-filter)

`App.js`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { process } from "@progress/kendo-data-query";
import { Grid, GridColumn as Column } from "@progress/kendo-react-grid";
import { ColumnMenu, ColumnMenuCheckboxFilter } from "./columnMenu";
import products from "./products.json";

const createDataState = (dataState) => {
  return {
    result: process(products.slice(0), dataState),
    dataState: dataState,
  };
}

const App = () => {
  let initialState = createDataState({ take: 8, skip: 0, });
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState(initialState.result);
  const [dataState, setDataState] = React.useState(initialState.dataState);
  const dataStateChange = (event) => {
    let updatedState = createDataState(event.dataState);
    setResult(updatedState.result);
    setDataState(updatedState.dataState);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      <Grid data={result} {...dataState} onDataStateChange={dataStateChange} sortable={true} pageable={true} pageSize={8} >
        <Column field="ProductID" title="Product Id" filter={"numeric"} columnMenu={ColumnMenu} />
        <Column field="ProductName" columnMenu={ColumnMenuCheckboxFilter} />
        <Column field="UnitPrice" filter={"numeric"} columnMenu={ColumnMenu} />
        <Column field="InsertedDate" filter={"date"} format="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" columnMenu={ColumnMenu} />
        <Column field="Discontinued" filter={"boolean"} columnMenu={ColumnMenuCheckboxFilter} />
      </Grid>
    </div >
  )
};

export default App;
```

`ColumnMenu.js`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { GridColumnMenuFilter, GridColumnMenuCheckboxFilter, } from "@progress/kendo-react-grid";
import products from "./products.json";

export const ColumnMenu = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <GridColumnMenuFilter {...props} expanded={true} />
        </div>
    );
};
export const ColumnMenuCheckboxFilter = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <GridColumnMenuCheckboxFilter
                {...props}
                data={products}
                expanded={true}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

[image]

Comment: @Eduards, this cannot change as of today. May be they will give a format option in future.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to achieve this, ultimately what you are trying to set is the `format` (and potentially the `formatPlaceholder`) of the `DateInput` in the `GridColumnMenuFilter`.

The best option depends on whether you want to do this selectively or for larger parts of your whole application. Your options are:

- Pass a custom `DateInput` to the the `filterUI` property of the `GridColumnMenuFilter` for any `GridColumn` you want to apply this to. This is useful if you only want it to apply to specific `GridColumn`s. See https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/columns/column-menu/#toc-customizing-the-filter-component/.
- Use the `IntlProvider` to make all child `DateInput`s (not just in `Grid`s) use the date format from your locale. This is useful if your locale follows the `dd-MM-yyyy` pattern and if you want to use `IntlProvider` to set this globally. As per the [DateInput documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dateinputs/dateinput/formats/) the format property for any `DateInput` is `'d'` by default; by using `IntlProvider` you are specifying what this default format is. Note that this doesn't change the default `formatPlaceholder` which will be `wide` (i.e. `day/month/year`) rather than the actual format pattern. The formats are retrieved from CLDR in this approach. Here is a functional StackBlitz demonstrating this approach: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-o5gz9j?file=app%2Fmain.tsx.
- Use `DateInputPropsContext` to specify the `format` and / or `formatPlaceholder` of all child `DateInput`s (not just in `Grid`s). As per the [KendoReact documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dateinputs/props-context/) this approach is provided specifically for this situation, but as stated will affect all child `DateInput` components. Here is another StackBlitz demonstrating this approach: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3pamhz?file=app%2Fmain.tsx.